# ZIP+4 ZIP codes in Contacts for Samsung Vibrant (Galaxy S)

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s

I have a Samsung Vibrant (Galaxy S) running Android 2.1-update1.  I have ZIP Codes for many of my contacts in the ZIP+4 format (e.g. 99999-1234). However, the field for ZIP codes does not allow any character except numbers.  Without being able to add a dash it makes it difficult to read (e.g 999991234).

I would have thought that it would auto-format the number they way it does for phone numbers.  Is there anyway to have the default Contacts program accept ZIP+4 ZIP code format?  Are there any alternative Contacts programs that provide the correct formatting for ZIP+4?  Is the Contacts program standard across manufacturers (e.g. part of the OS)?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but if you create them on Google Contacts, you can enter the dash and it will show up correctly on the phone.  If you create them on the phone, you can edit them to have the dash on Google Contacts after they get synced there; on the next sync, they'll have the dash on the phone.

Comment: Well, at least that is a solution.  However, I would really like something that doesn't require syncing, editing, and re-syncing just to enter information that by default should be able to be correctly formatted when first entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that entering ZIP Codes directly in the Contacts app in the ZIP+4 format under Android 2.1-update1 is **not** possible. However, I just updated to Froyo (2.2) (T959UVKA6).  Not only can the Contacts/ Storage app natively import and export contacts to and from the microSD card, but it also allows directly entering ZIP+4 *with the dash* in the ZIP Code field!